# Get Am/PM value from Nullable TimeSpan

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm getting time from database received as  class TimeSpan. In order to diplay as Am/PM I switched it over to DateTime

```
 @string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", new DateTime().Add(t.BegTime))
```

This worked.

As soon as I changed TimeSpan to allow Nulls it stopped working. Why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
@string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", new DateTime().Add(t.BegTime.HasValue ? t.BegTime.Value : new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)));
```

This answer also assumes t.BegTime is a Nullable TimeSpan

Comment: Why when I do this does a NULL value show up as 12AM??

Comment: That is what TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) is. If you want a null DateTime to produce something else, you just need to replace TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) with what you want.

Comment: The thing is, you can't use string.Format on a null value, so you need to detect nulls and provide a suitable value to be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", new DateTime().Add(t.BegTime.Value))
```

Nullable types have a "Value" property.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

EDIT:  As Igor pointed out, this code will fail if the BegTime is Null.  It is still your responsibility to wrap this with a guard statement to check for that possibility.

Comment: True, I shouldn't assume the OP knows that.  I'll edit.

Comment: I'm assuming BegTime is the nullable timespan and t is some other structure (strongly typed row or similar) since TimeSpan doesn't have a BegTime property.  Maybe the OP can clarify.